# Setting up Unity Smart Merge\UnityYAMLMerge with Git,"No such file or directory"

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, git-merge

When I input this in git bash

```
git merge
```

I got

```
Normal merge conflict for 'Library/ArtifactDB':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 141: <C:/Q/test-games/unityEditor/2021.3.5f1c1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe>: No such file or directory
Library/ArtifactDB seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful [y/n]?
```

I add this to config

```
[merge]
tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
trustExitCode = false
cmd = '<C:/Q/test-games/unityEditor/2021.3.5f1c1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
```

**-------------------------------------**

I'm sure my path is right.I type this in my computer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6fih.png)

and I got

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FIul.png)

**-------------------------------------**

And my unity projectSetting VersionControl is "Visible meta files",Editor-AssetSerialization-Mode is"ForceText"

I tried to modify my path to

<C:\\Q\\test-games\\unityEditor\\2021.3.5f1c1\\Editor\\Data\\Tools\\UnityYAMLMerge.exe>

but still got the same answer.

I also rename the "test-game"folder  "testGame",and modify my path to

<C:/Q/testGames/unityEditor/2021.3.5f1c1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe>

It also failed.

**-------------------------------------**

The detailed contents are as follows

my git bash

```
 ASUS@LAPTOP-5COEIH28 MINGW64 /c/Q/test-games/project/unity/WarSimulator/WarSimulator (test1|MERGING)
$ git mergetool
Merging:
Library/ArtifactDB
Library/Bee/backend_profiler0.traceevents
Library/Bee/fullprofile.json
Library/Bee/tundra.digestcache
Library/Search/transactions.db
Library/SourceAssetDB
Library/StateCache/SceneView/8c/8cd7c613bf844de3b80696e27a479d5e.json
Logs/AssetImportWorker0-prev_BACKUP_859-prev.log
Logs/AssetImportWorker0-prev_BASE_859-prev.log
Logs/AssetImportWorker1.log
UserSettings/Layouts/default-2021.dwlt

Normal merge conflict for 'Library/ArtifactDB':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 141: <C:/Q/test-games/unityEditor/2021.3.5f1c1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe>: No such file or directory
Library/ArtifactDB seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful [y/n]?
```

my gitattributes

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto
*.unity binary
*.prefab binary
*.asset binary
```

my config

```
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[merge]
tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
trustExitCode = false
cmd = '<C:\\Q\\test-games\\unityEditor\\2021.3.5f1c1\\Editor\\Data\\Tools\\UnityYAMLMerge.exe>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
[branch "test1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/test1

[merge]
tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
trustExitCode = false
cmd = '<C:/Q/test-games/unityEditor/2021.3.5f1c1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
[branch "test2"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/test2
```

**-------------------------------------**

How can I solve it ?Help!Help!

Comment: Why the < and > round the exe name?

Comment: unityDoc says    cmd = '<path to UnityYAMLMerge>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"

Comment: I deleted <>and got a pop-up window said"Unity YAMLMerge error:unknow command.\Library\ArtifactDB_REMOTE_679"

Comment: <something> is usually used to denote something to enter a value.  At least now its running it.